# How can I declare a config.h file, add it to my App-Prefix.pch, and then use it globally in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create a Config.h file to house all my static const strings that should be global to my application.

I've created a new Config.h file, but there are a few things I'm unaware of.

1) How do I declare variables. A or B?

A)

```
#define hotelURLString4 = @"http://blah.herokuapp.com/api/v1/hotels/";
```

B)

```
static NSString * const hotelURLString2 = @"http://blah.herokuapp.com/api/v1/hotels/";
```

2) I can't seem to use this file. If I try to import the Config.h directly into a file of mine, I get a "Config.h file not found" error in xcode. If I include it in my AppName-Prefix.pch up at the top via...

```
#import <Availability.h>
#import "Config.h"

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

That does not seem to work either. How do I do this.

3) How do I access the variable declared/defined. Do I call Config.hotelURLString, or [Config hotelURLString]... or how do I access it?

===================================================================
============================ UPDATE ===============================

1) I created my header like this... am I not doing something correctly, because I tried again and it won't work either.[image: Adding a .h header file.]

2) This is my AppName-Prefix.pch file.

```
#import <Availability.h>
#import "Config.h"
#import "MyHeader.h"

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

3) Here is my Project Navigator [image: Project Navigator]

Comment: How did you create the file exactly?  Is it listed in the file browser in Xcode?

Comment: FYI - If you go with option "A", get rid of the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 1, method B is probably better, although you should name your variable more like:

```
kHoteUrlString2
```

And preferably something more descriptive then just the numbers, but the main point here is the lower case k and the uppercase first letter.  This is a C/ObjC naming convention for constants.

---

As for question 2, it sounds like your file isn't actually in the project.  Some more details are needed to answer this part of the question, and I'll update my answer if the question has more details added.

---

As for question 3, you use the variable exactly as you would as if you had declared it at the top of whatever file you're using.  Objective-C doesn't have namespaces.

Comment: Thanks! I've added some details, can you answer #2. I added a few screenshots and some code, but don't seem to be able to add this new file for some reason.